# Check Device Root Status Using Google SafetyNet

Tags: java, android, root

My Question is simple, Can i use google SafetyNet to check if my application running on Rooted device ? if not, what is the most recommended tool, SDK or library for android ?

Answer (score 0):

SafetyNet is not designed to detect the device is rooted or not.

You can check documentation from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation)

I suggest you to use RootBeer library. We use this library in production environment without any issues.